# Can someone please explain to me the purpose of the asterisk in Python?

Tags: python

For instance, can someone please explain to me the purpose of the asterisk in line 2 below?

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max())
x, y = m(*np.meshgrid(lat,lon))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it will "expand" a collection in its individual elements.

So, suppose a function needs many arguments, and you have these arguments in a collection. Since you could not pass the collection itself (which would count as a single argument), you use the `*` so the collection is expanded and passed as its individual arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

`An asterisk * denotes iterable unpacking. Its operand must be an iterable. The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.`

Comment: Note the bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) re: questions which "...have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Thank you to the two that answered my question. I saw the other posted questions already which did not clearly answer what I was specifically asking. The Stack Overlords may do as they wish with my question now.