# How to compose a list with conditional elements

Tags: python

I program in python for a while and I've found that this language is very programmer friendly, so that maybe there is a technique that I don't know how to compose a list with conditional elements. The simplified example is:

```py
# in pseudo code
add_two = True
my_list = [
  "one",
  "two" if add_two,
  "three",
]
```

Basically I'm looking for a handy way to create a list that contains some that are added under some specific condition.

Some alternatives that don't look such nice:

```py
add_two = True

# option 1
my_list = []
my_list += ["one"]
my_list += ["two"] if add_two else []
my_list += ["three"]


# option 2
my_list = []
my_list += ["one"]
if add_two: my_list += ["two"]
my_list += ["three"]
```

Is there something that can simplify it? Cheers!

Comment: Any chance you can create a list of `True` and `False` for the values you want to include? Something like `[True, True, False, True]` to generate `['one', 'two', 'four']`?

Comment: @Engineero but how are the bools swapped out for other values in any more of an efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

This approach uses a `None` sentinel value for values to remove, then filters them out at the end. If your data contains `None` already, you can [create another sentinel object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52884110/2958070) to use instead.

```
add_two = True
my_list = [
    "one",
    "two" if add_two else None,
    "three",
]

my_list = [e for e in my_list if e is not None]

print(my_list)
# ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can create a list of bools representing what elements you want to keep from a candidate list, you can do this pretty succinctly. For example:

```
candidates = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
include = [True, True, False, True, False]
result = [c for c, i in zip(candidates, include) if i]
print(result)
# ['one', 'two', 'four']
```

If you can use numpy, this gets even more succinct:

```
import numpy as np
candidates = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
include = [True, True, False, True, False]
print(candidates[include])  # can use boolean indexing directly!
# ['one', 'two', 'four']
```

Finally, as suggested in a comment, you can use [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress). Note that this returns an iterator, so you have to unpack it.

```
from itertools import compress
print([v for v in compress(candidates, include)])
# ['one', 'two', 'four']
```

Comment: This is what [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.compress) is used for :) `result = itertools.compress(candidates, include)`

Answer (score 4):

Another one line approach, which is more Pythonic in my opinion, would be:

```
add_two = True    
my_list = ['one'] + ['two'] * add_two + ['three']
```

In case of multiple conditionned elements, I think other alternatives, such as list of bools, should be used.

Comment: Multiplication! Brilliant! Adding unpacking we get: `[1, *[2]*False, 3]` → `[1, 3]` and `[1, *[2]*True]` → `[1, 2, 3]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In one line you can write:

```
my_list = ['one'] + (['two'] if add_two else []) + ['three']
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [x for x in ('one', 'two' if add_two else '', 'three') if x]
```

Or the functional way to remove Falsy values:

```
my_list = list(filter(None, ('one', 'two' if add_two else '', 'three')))
```

Answer (score 2):

First I'd write a simple predicate function that determines whether or not a value should be included. Let's pretend that in this list of integers you only want to include those numbers `>0`.

```
def is_strictly_positive(x):
    return x > 0
```

Then you can have your whole list of numbers:

```
lst = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And filter them:

```
filter(is_strictly_positive, lst)  # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

which creates a `filter` object -- a generator that produces the values you need once. If you need a whole list, you can either do:

```
new_lst = list(filter(is_strictly_positive, lst))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

or, idiomatically, use a list comprehension

```
new_lst = [x for x in lst if is_strictly_positive(x)]  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

You can also use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.compress) to produce a similar result to `filter`, but it's a little over-engineered in this simple case.

```
new_lst_gen = itertools.compress(lst, map(is_strictly_positive, lst))  # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` module has many useful functions:

```
from itertools import compress, dropwhile, takewhile, filterfalse

condition1 = True
condition2 = False
condition3 = True
l = list(range(10))

print(list(compress(['a', 'b', 'c'], [condition1, condition2, condition3])))
# ['a', 'c']

print(list(dropwhile(lambda x: x > 5, l)))
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 5, l)))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print(list(filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2, l))) # returns elements whose predicates == False
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question right now (coming from dartlang / flutter where you can just write `if` in between the list of elements).

Came up with a solution which looks like that for python:

```py
[
  'some_element',
  *[some_other for some_other in [some_other] if your_condition
]
```

you could make that more readable by something like this, though:

```py
def maybe_include(element: Any, condition: Callable[[Any], bool) -> list[Any]:
  return list(element) if condition(element) else []  

# ...(somewhere else)...
[
  'some_element',
  *maybe_include(element, lambda element: your_condition),
  'more_static_elements', 
  ...
]
```

althought this is indeed a bit ugly, it works completely inplace and can be used fluently within declarative definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using boolean multiplication and list unpacking (expanded from [@denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936673/denis)'s comment):

`*[value]*condition`

The first `*` unpacks the value and the second `*` multiplies by the boolean condition to include or exclude it.

```
is_home_alone = False
is_filthy_animal = True

my_list = [
    *['--home-alone']*is_home_alone,
    *['--count-to-ten']*is_filthy_animal,
    *['one', 2., 10]*is_filthy_animal, # Multiple types and values
]

# returns: ['--count-to-ten', 'one', 2.0, 10]
```

Comment: That's quite elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [
  "one",
  *("two" for _i in range(1) if add_two),
  "three",
]
```

The idea is to use the list comprehension syntax to construct either a single-element list with item "two", if add_two is True, or an empty list, if add_two is False, and then unpack it.

Comment: Is the asterisk for multiplication?  What is being multiplied, if so?  Can you elaborate at all?  It looks self-explanatory but I don't follow.

Comment: @harperville The asterisk is not for multiplication, but for [iterable unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53808024/2745495). And this is a good example why people should explain their answers, because it is not self-explanatory. Doing iterable unpacking on a 1-element iterable with `range(1)` is just so unnecessary.